# List of available colors that show up in CSS in Visual Studio code?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Anytime I edit a css file in Visual Studio code, a list of colors shows up.

For example,

```
  background-color: blue;
```

I appreciate the functionality and the ability to see and edit colors in the code editor.

The ability to type in the name of the colors is very useful.
However, I realize it's not the easiest to find specific colors beyond the basic colors when I try filtering by name/IntelliSense.

There seems to be very long list of colors - is there pattern or complete list of colors that I can refer to? I'd like to see the full list so I can easily refer to the colors in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.

What you're seeing are `<named-color>` which is a [CSS data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Types).

EDIT: You can use [this page](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/css/css-color.html) which groups then into color categories.

You can see a reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/named-color).

In case you don't want to click through - here is the list - I'll split into the specs which was started in 1996 and most recently in 2014 with more recent edits.

CSS Level 1

| color | hexcode |
| --- | --- |
| black | #000000 |
| silver | #c0c0c0 |
| gray | #808080 |
| white | #ffffff |
| maroon | #800000 |
| red | #ff0000 |
| purple | #800080 |
| fuchsia | #ff00ff |
| green | #008000 |
| lime | #00ff00 |
| olive | #808000 |
| yellow | #ffff00 |
| navy | #000080 |
| blue | #0000ff |
| teal | #008080 |
| aqua | #00ffff |

CSS Level 2

| color | hexcode |
| --- | --- |
| orange | #ffa500 |

CSS Level 3

| color | hexcode |
| --- | --- |
| aliceblue | #f0f8ff |
| antiquewhite | #faebd7 |
| aquamarine | #7fffd4 |
| azure | #f0ffff |
| beige | #f5f5dc |
| bisque | #ffe4c4 |
| blanchedalmond | #ffebcd |
| blueviolet | #8a2be2 |
| brown | #a52a2a |
| burlywood | #deb887 |
| cadetblue | #5f9ea0 |
| chartreuse | #7fff00 |
| chocolate | #d2691e |
| coral | #ff7f50 |
| cornflowerblue | #6495ed |
| cornsilk | #fff8dc |
| crimson | #dc143c |
| cyan (synonym of aqua) | #00ffff |
| darkblue | #00008b |
| darkcyan | #008b8b |
| darkgoldenrod | #b8860b |
| darkgray | #a9a9a9 |
| darkgreen | #006400 |
| darkgrey | #a9a9a9 |
| darkkhaki | #bdb76b |
| darkmagenta | #8b008b |
| darkolivegreen | #556b2f |
| darkorange | #ff8c00 |
| darkorchid | #9932cc |
| darkred | #8b0000 |
| darksalmon | #e9967a |
| darkseagreen | #8fbc8f |
| darkslateblue | #483d8b |
| darkslategray | #2f4f4f |
| darkslategrey | #2f4f4f |
| darkturquoise | #00ced1 |
| darkviolet | #9400d3 |
| deeppink | #ff1493 |
| deepskyblue | #00bfff |
| dimgray | #696969 |
| dimgrey | #696969 |
| dodgerblue | #1e90ff |
| firebrick | #b22222 |
| floralwhite | #fffaf0 |
| forestgreen | #228b22 |
| gainsboro | #dcdcdc |
| ghostwhite | #f8f8ff |
| gold | #ffd700 |
| goldenrod | #daa520 |
| greenyellow | #adff2f |
| grey | #808080 |
| honeydew | #f0fff0 |
| hotpink | #ff69b4 |
| indianred | #cd5c5c |
| indigo | #4b0082 |
| ivory | #fffff0 |
| khaki | #f0e68c |
| lavender | #e6e6fa |
| lavenderblush | #fff0f5 |
| lawngreen | #7cfc00 |
| lemonchiffon | #fffacd |
| lightblue | #add8e6 |
| lightcoral | #f08080 |
| lightcyan | #e0ffff |
| lightgoldenrodyellow | #fafad2 |
| lightgray | #d3d3d3 |
| lightgreen | #90ee90 |
| lightgrey | #d3d3d3 |
| lightpink | #ffb6c1 |
| lightsalmon | #ffa07a |
| lightseagreen | #20b2aa |
| lightskyblue | #87cefa |
| lightslategray | #778899 |
| lightslategrey | #778899 |
| lightsteelblue | #b0c4de |
| lightyellow | #ffffe0 |
| limegreen | #32cd32 |
| linen | #faf0e6 |
| magenta |  |
| (synonym of fuchsia) | #ff00ff |
| mediumaquamarine | #66cdaa |
| mediumblue | #0000cd |
| mediumorchid | #ba55d3 |
| mediumpurple | #9370db |
| mediumseagreen | #3cb371 |
| mediumslateblue | #7b68ee |
| mediumspringgreen | #00fa9a |
| mediumturquoise | #48d1cc |
| mediumvioletred | #c71585 |
| midnightblue | #191970 |
| mintcream | #f5fffa |
| mistyrose | #ffe4e1 |
| moccasin | #ffe4b5 |
| navajowhite | #ffdead |
| oldlace | #fdf5e6 |
| olivedrab | #6b8e23 |
| orangered | #ff4500 |
| orchid | #da70d6 |
| palegoldenrod | #eee8aa |
| palegreen | #98fb98 |
| paleturquoise | #afeeee |
| palevioletred | #db7093 |
| papayawhip | #ffefd5 |
| peachpuff | #ffdab9 |
| peru | #cd853f |
| pink | #ffc0cb |
| plum | #dda0dd |
| powderblue | #b0e0e6 |
| rosybrown | #bc8f8f |
| royalblue | #4169e1 |
| saddlebrown | #8b4513 |
| salmon | #fa8072 |
| sandybrown | #f4a460 |
| seagreen | #2e8b57 |
| seashell | #fff5ee |
| sienna | #a0522d |
| skyblue | #87ceeb |
| slateblue | #6a5acd |
| slategray | #708090 |
| slategrey | #708090 |
| snow | #fffafa |
| springgreen | #00ff7f |
| steelblue | #4682b4 |
| tan | #d2b48c |
| thistle | #d8bfd8 |
| tomato | #ff6347 |
| transparent | See transparent. |
| turquoise | #40e0d0 |
| violet | #ee82ee |
| wheat | #f5deb3 |
| whitesmoke | #f5f5f5 |
| yellowgreen | #9acd32 |

Transparent is a shortcut for rgba(0,0,0,0). For those not familiar the that is 0 for red a red value, 0 for a green value, 0 for a blue value, and importantly 0 for the alpha value which the transparency value (lower is more transparent).

CSS Level 4

| color | hexcode |
| --- | --- |
| rebeccapurple | #663399 |

Source: mdn web docs

Answer (score -1):

After you type the code, just hover with your mouse on top of the color - move your mouse pointer on top of the color name/code.
This is supposed to show you a panel where you can edit the color and its opacity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).